How to achieve a smooth page redirect with an animation?
I'm trying to get an effect where a user is redirected to another page in the middle of an animation, so to the user, it would seem like there is only an animation however, the user has already been redirected to another page. This allows for a smooth page redirect instead of a load in to another page.
In my code i set it up so when i click on the button and the animations begins with the div containing an image expanding, once the image has reached full screen width and height, a redirect has been already been ran, resulting in a effect where the image covers the entire screen, and the user now enters to a different page. To conclude it, i am trying to get a super smooth redirect in the middle of an animation, redirecting the user another page without them realizing it.
Similar to (https://www.metalab.com/). “U can enter the page and click on one of the buttons to see the effect”
This is the effect I’m looking for (https://youtu.be/ME5-4Xc-V-A)
This is a simillar effect (https://youtu.be/VNLmL9CSOvk?si=D0fNXvOdZYCjVslH)
"Both are related to the effect i want where there is a smooth transition/redirect between pages animation."
this is the effect "I have" (https://youtu.be/iHwd0k3k4J0)
<div class="buttonparent">
    <button class="hover-btn" data-target="slide1">Ro</button>
</div>
<div id="slide1" class="slide-out-div left-to-right slide1-1">
    <img src="./foto/codingpic.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<style>
    body {
        background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .buttonparent {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        gap: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30%;
        left: 2%;
    }
    .hover-btn {
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
        backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 50px;
        color: white;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: border-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    .hover-btn:hover {
        background: transparent;
        border-color: white;
        color: white;
    }
    .slide-out-div {
        position: absolute;
        width: 300px;
        height: 150px;
        opacity: 0;
        clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
        transition: clip-path 0.5s ease-out, opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    }
    .slide-out-div.left-to-right {
        clip-path: inset(0 100% 0 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .slide-out-div.left-to-right.active {
        clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .slide1-1 {
        top: 20vh;
        left: 20vw;
        width: 30vw;
        height: 15vw;
    }
    .slide-out-div.expanded {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        opacity: 1;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 0;
        transition: all 0.8s ease-in;
    }
    body.expanded-mode {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<script>
    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.hover-btn');
    const divs = document.querySelectorAll('.slide-out-div');

    buttons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            divs.forEach((div) => div.classList.remove('active'));
            const targetId = button.getAttribute('data-target');
            const targetDiv = document.getElementById(targetId);
            if (targetDiv) {
                targetDiv.classList.add('active');
            }
        });
        button.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            const targetId = button.getAttribute('data-target');
            const targetDiv = document.getElementById(targetId);
            if (targetDiv) {
                targetDiv.classList.remove('active');
            }
        });
        button.addEventListener('click', () => {
            const targetId = button.getAttribute('data-target');
            const targetDiv = document.getElementById(targetId);
            if (targetDiv) {
                targetDiv.classList.add('expanded');
                document.body.classList.add('expanded-mode');
                document.querySelector('.buttonparent').style.display = 'none';
                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.location.href = 'diu.html';
                }, 800);
            }
        });
    });

    function preloadResources() {
        fetch('diu.html')
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(data => {
                window.preloadedHTML = data;
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error preloading diu.html:', error));
        let link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'preload';
        link.href = 'diu.css';
        link.as = 'style';
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', preloadResources);
</script>


At first I tried including everything into 1 html css and js file however that seemed to make things super difficult having to set changing overflows, managing other js context and switching it between pages. following some research on sites with similar effects, instead what they all do is redirect the user to another page. So I tired preloading, prefetching and some js to load and redirect to other page smoothly, however it all just turns out choppy and glitchy. Above is my code, this is the mainpage code, if u look at the javascript I mentioned the page that its supposed to redirect too when I click on the button. I cant seem to get that effect of a smooth transition to another page. it just looks glitchy and laggy even after I have preloaded the content.
can it be done with html css and vanilla js? I’m still a beginner, quite unfamiliar with js frameworks

I didn't read your full specification there, but you should probably go look into the View Transitions API.

I doubt many sites doing this are actually loading a new page, they're usually single page apps that manage the URL.

I checked the website you've linked. There's is an ajax (xhr) request made on every hover or menu click. It does not load at all a new page. It is by the way the only way to achieve what you wish to do. Loading a new page goes exactly against any type of control over what/when is happening on the ui

@anaitslimane hello, no matter what if i see smooth transitions between site pages, it will be done using ajax? Lets say when i click on a button and there is a smooth loading page to a diff page of the website "no sudden changes similar to a refresh"?

@user26492082 Yes exactly, asynchronous requests are the only way. But don't worry, it is not a workaround or a weird way to do that way. It's completely normal, especially now, with the growing popularity of Single Page Applications
